# Rails 3 - modifying an attribute of other model after model.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, attr, after-save

Unfortunately I'm probably still too much a Rails beginner, so, even though I thought about and tried different approaches, I didn't get to work what I want and now have to ask for help again.

I have a REST comment vote mechanism with thumbs up and down for each comment. That works fine, each handled with counter_cache to count. Now, based on these thumbs up and down votes, I want to calculate a plusminus value for each comment, thumbs_up-votes - thumbs_down-votes. Although I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way to deal with that, I am planning to have the plus-minus value as an extra integer attribute of the comment model (whereas the thumbs up and down are own models).  So, what I basically want is, that when a thumbs_up is saved, the comment's plusminus attr automatically should be `+= 1`, and respectively for the thumbs_down.save `a -= 1`.

How can I issue such an action from within the thumbs_up controller? Do I need to modify my form_for or is my approach completely wrong?

Is there an after_save callback to deal with an attribute of a different model?

Comment: Why do you need a thumbs_up controller? It doesn't seem like you should need to store thumbs_up or thumbs_down, from what you've given. Unless, that is, you want to display the amount of thumbs_up and thumbs_down...

Comment: yep, I'm displaying those votes and furthermore there is a 24h vote restriction. So it's easier to deal with that with extra thumbs up/down models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've given, it's hard to tell. But I'd say that if you need to show a comment's "thumbs up" and "thumbs down" independently, store them as fields for your Comment model. Then, just making a helper method in your Comment model to get a comment's rating:

```
   def rating
      thumbs_up - thumbs_down
   end
```

**Edit:**
With your new comment, I'd still say make a helper method rather than a field.

```
   #models/comment.rb
   def rating
      thumbs_up.all.length - thumbs_down.all.length #or whatever way you want to do this
   end
```

Comment: I mean my thumbs up and down votes work fine, they are saved as a list, with only 2 columns, id and comment_id; and then counted via counter_cache. Now, building up on that I want to calculate this "plusminus" value, when a "thumbs_up" or "thumbs_down" is saved.

Comment: @rails_has_elegance Right. So make it a helper method, like I've shown above. Making another field is unnecessary and thus counterproductive.

Comment: @rails_has_elegance I just said `rating` because that is a little more intuitive than calling it `plusminus` ;). If your implementation is a little different, that's fine: it's impossible for me to know how to code this without seeing your code.

Comment: Would it be possible to order comments based upon a helper method? Like a `@comments.order("rating DESC")`
I thought you could only order models based upon their attributes. I like that helper method, but is this sorting doable with it? And thank you for your help!

Comment: @rails_has_elegance I'm pretty sure. It would just be a normal Ruby `sort`

Comment: After all, you can order things by methods like `a.name.downcase`... so I'm pretty sure methods' return values are interpreted as attributes. Give it a shot -- shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to perform a sort in a SQL command or something? Fetch all of the comments, then perform a Ruby Array#sort on them. Also, mark this answer as the solution if this answers your question ;)

Comment: Example syntax: `comments = Comments.all`, `comments.sort! { |a,b| a.rating <=> b.rating }`

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted my last comment instead of editing it. Currently when using `<%= render @comments.order("rating DESC") %>`, I get the following error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: rating: ...` Do I maybe need to deal with the helper method differently when ordering? I'll google it

Comment: Yeah, there may be a way to use the helper, but I think the most sure way of doing it is just to do a normal Ruby array sort in your controller.

Comment: Everything works fine now, except that it won't let me paginate these newly sorted comments saying `undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x31753c8>` using will_paginate. I don't get why. Shouldn't it be common for will_paginate to paginate arrays?

Comment: fixed it. Had to include 'require 'will_paginate/array''.
Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to mix two different models with helper methods that don't actually belong to neither of those models, you can use Observers http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

your observer will watch one model and do something